# Smooth Scroll to Top of Div triggered by Bootstrap Toggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, smooth-scrolling

I want to use smooth scroll to animate to the div which opens (I also want it to remove the button on click); however, I don't want to use a fixed offset for the smooth scroll.

I have tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#toggleContact').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
 $(this).remove();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#DIV_ID').offset().top - 20
    }, 'slow');
});</script>
```

Here is a Fiddle: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s7sq58v2/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
// To remove button, you can also use .hide() instead .remove()
$('.opencontact').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
    $(this).remove();
});

// To scroll when collapse is completed
$('#toggleContact').on("shown.bs.collapse", function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 20
    }, 'slow');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/s7sq58v2/26/)

Comment: For some reason I added it to scripts.js on http://pivoture.com/ux-service-offerings/user-experience-analysis and something is preventing it from working, could it be the version of jQuery?

Comment: Yes, seems to be the jQuery version. You can [consult here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/bower.json) which versions of jQuery are supported in last version. Maybe you need `"jquery": ">= 1.9.1"` in your website ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I used a WP plugin to update to latest jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the button you can use:

```
 $('.opencontact').hide();
```

You may want to assign an id to the button so other classes are not affected.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#toggleContact').on('click', function(event) {event.preventDefault();     // To prevent following the link (optional)
$(this).remove();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#DIV_ID').offset().top - 20
}, 'slow');
$('.opencontact').hide();
});
</script>
```

You should add the javascript code to your fiddle so it can be easily edited and debugged.